# Android remotely install app

Tags: android, installation

This android app "Plan B" claims that you can install and run it remotely, without having the phone in front of you.

http://android-tips.com/remote-install-an-app-after-you-loose-your-phone-to-locate-it/

Is this a new type of android feature?  Is this available to any android developer? Has anyone used it?  (Installing an app remotely)

Comment: The link no longer works in 2020.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookout (the developer of ("Plan B") is taking advantage of the ability provided by the new [Google Market website](https://market.android.com/) that allows users to install market apps to their phones from the web.  To quote from the [Google Mobile Blog](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2011/02/introducing-android-market-website.html):

> You can also send apps directly to your Android device with just a few clicks—no wires needed.

[Looking at the permissions](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) the app uses, you can see that they have the ability to "receive SMS" messages.  They probably use a [method like this](http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html) to remotely start their app.  When an SMS message is received, the app starts, checks to see if the special message it is looking for has been received, and if so, begins performing its location function.

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Do you know if there are other ways that you could remotely start an application process through the app other than text?

Comment: You could use a push notification.  Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: but in order to send a message, you would first need to have the phone's number or GCM id registered on the server to send the message to start the app

Answer (score 0):

Remote app installation has been available through the Android Market Webstore since it launched around Feb this year. It's very simple to use and your device will synchronize with newly installed apps as soon as a data connection is available.